# Is there a way to change the language on Overleaf?

Tags: languages

Things like date, contents and bibliography come out in English, but I´d like to have them in Portuguese. I tried changing the settings, but didn´t find anything. Is there a package for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be possible with the babel package.

Try including this:

```
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}

\selectlanguage{portuges}
```

And if there are certain letters not being encoded include the following:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks. Please note it's \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}.

Comment: @Martin -- In fact, options `portuguese`,  `brazilian`, and `brazil` all load language `portuges`.  (That is, it is not a matter of how the language happens to be spelled in English.)